# Excel - conditional formatting with multiple criteria doesn't work

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to color a cell red when the contents matches (at least) one of two other cells.

I've been trying this:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(CB17:CE17;CB55)=1,COUNTIF(CB18:CE18;CB55)=1)
```

and this:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(CB17:CE17;CB55)=1,COUNTIF(CB18:CE18;CB55)=1) = TRUE
```

but Excel doesn't recognize this as a formula ("There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? ...")!

I can't get any conditional formatting formula to work with the AND operator it seems (and my Excel is the English version).

Any advice?

Edit:
some screenshots to clarify:

Error I get when using AND or the '+' operator in the formula:
[image: Error I get when using AND or the '+' operator in the formula]

Current contents of the criteria cells:
[image: Current contents of the criteria cells]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND will be true of the expression inside results to true.

First of, you do not need to evaluate to 1 for AND to work. Secondly, you used ; and , instead of ;. You mentioned changing them to ; solved it.

So `=AND( COUNTIF(...), COUNTIF(...) )` would already be enough.

Your formula would be `=AND(COUNTIF(CB17:CE17;CB55);COUNTIF(CB18:CE18;CB55))`

Now that being said, you want it to work for either of the values being true, that means you need an OR operator, not AND. The syntax is basically the same, just replace AND with OR. Your formula would be `=OR(COUNTIF(CB17:CE17;CB55);COUNTIF(CB18:CE18;CB55))`

Now since your ranges are CB17:CE17 and CB18:CE18 and they both evaluate to CB55, you could of course simply use `=COUNTIF(CB17:CE18;CB55)` which would be a lot simpler. I have explained the AND so you can learn from it, in case you really need to use more ranges and/or evaluate against different cells.

Comment: an alternate form could be '=COUNTIF(CB17:CE17,CB55)+COUNTIF(CB18:CE18,CB55)` since any integer greater than 0 is true?

Comment: Since he is looking for 1 or more matches in EITHER of the checks, should it not be an OR function instead of AND?

Comment: You're right. I'll edit accordingly. Also, not sure about the anything other than 0 being true though.

Comment: Do a test statement of `=if(3,true,false)`

Comment: @ForwardEd that does not test anything. It basically does this: IF 3=3? which it is, its true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

1. While =COUNTIF(CB17:CE17,CB55)=1 works, =COUNTIF(CB17:CE18,CB55)=1 doesn't work: the cell loses its red color when I change CE17 to CE18. (Don't ask me why, I didn't change the contents of the criteria cells!)

2. =AND(COUNTIF(CB17:CE17,CB55),COUNTIF(CB18:CE18,CB55)) doesn't work for the same reason my formula didn't work: Excel still doesn't seem te recognize the AND operator as a formula but thinks I want to enter text!

Comment: @LChip, 3 is the logical check, there is no =, change it to any integer you want.  I am not sure about the negatives, but I am sure about the positives. if you prefer, try `IF(A1, true, false)` and then populate A1 with various numbers

Comment: Can it be that there's something in on the 18th row that causes the countif to stop working? such as empty cells?

Comment: @LPChip just remembered it being explained to me once that excel considers 0 to be FALSE, therefore any other number is TRUE.

Comment: if you are counting string values, remember to make sure there are no trailing spaces.  "Space" is not the same as "Space " or " Space"

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF(CB17:CE18,CB55)>0` if the value is both rows, making it equal to 1 would through a false. @ExReey

Comment: I added some screenshots to clarify

Comment: @ExReey, edit your own question, not the answer.  I think you accidently hit the wrong edit button.

Comment: The screenshots were added to the original post.

I've solved the problem though: I have to use ";" instead of "," in the formula, otherwise I get the error!!
So now =COUNTIF(CB17:CE17;CB55)+COUNTIF(CB18:CE18;CB55) works perfectly!

Comment: Hmm, in the newest version they added support for the , but I'll edit my post accordingly.